# Laravel on Localhost - Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

Tags: laravel, email, mailgun, laravel-mail

I am trying to use Mailgun

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),


MAILGUN_DOMAIN=xxxxxxxxxx,
MAILGUN_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxx,

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp



MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

The error is a strange one. Why would it be trying to connect to gmail?

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

Edit:

```
Now I am getting

"mail" => array:9 [▼
      "driver" => "smtp"
      "host" => "smtp.mailgun.org"
      "port" => "2525"
      "from" => array:2 [▶]
      "encryption" => null
      "username" => null
      "password" => null
      "sendmail" => "/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs"
      "markdown" => array:2 [▼
        "theme" => "default"
```

Comment: May you need execute `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: Please try to debug your `dd(env('MAIL_HOST'));` And clear your cache.

Comment: dd(env('MAIL_HOST')); is null

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's look like your `.ENV` still have cache.

Please try this way

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

And try to debug at your `Controller`

```
dd(env('MAIL_HOST'));
```

If it's still get `smtp.gmail.com`. Please try this way.

Edit your `config/app.php`. And add below `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),`

```
'mail_host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
```

And try to debug at your `Controller`

```
dd(config('app.mail_host'));
```

I'm sure it's will show `smtp.mailgun.org`

After that you can delete the line you has just added to `config/app.php`

Answer (score 14):

My **MAIL_HOST** was `mailtrap.io`, and it seems that that URL is not valid any more.

When I changed it to `smtp.mailtrap.io` it started working again.

Comment: This was causing issues for me just a moment ago – very good to know!

Comment: Wow, thank you.  I was banging my head - this helped!

Comment: This is the exact solution to my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was going insane due to this reason. Thanks a lot. It helped.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.env`file you should set

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_USERNAME=(yourmailgunusername)
MAIL_PASSWORD=(yourmailgunpassword)
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
```

You can refer to these tutorials for more informations
[Mailgun setup with Laravel 5 example](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/mailgun-setup-with-laravel-5-exampleexample.html)
[Ultimate Guide on Sending Email in Laravel](https://scotch.io/tutorials/ultimate-guide-on-sending-email-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

After

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

You probably also need to restart your web server.