# Laravel: error when sending email

Tags: php, laravel

Im getting this error when sending an email with Laravel?

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]
```

Can anyone help with this? all the other questions just say change the driver but that just doesn't work.

Comment: try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002481/laravel-on-localhost-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail

Comment: Need to see more config to answer this..